# Mutable object is not changed by a function. How to debug it?

Tags: python

I came across one situation, which I can not reproduce in a simpler context (so, sorry for not providing a completely reproducible example). The situation is following. I have a large class and one method (let it call test). This method takes OrderedDict (from collections package) as an argument and changes it, but returns some string. I know that dictionary is a mutable object, so I do not need to return it (at least in theory). However, what is strange is that when I return from this method, my dictionary argument remains unchanged. So, if I simplify it, the code flow looks like this:

```
 from collections import OrderedDict as dord

 # large large class...

 #class method
    def test (self, obj):
        obj['b'] = 2
        print("BEFORE: ")
        print(obj)
        return "Hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = TestClass()
    obj = dord()
    obj['a'] = 1          
    c.test(obj)
    print("AFTER: ")
    print(obj)
```

And this is what I see in the console:

```
>>> Before:
>>> OrderedDict([('a', '1'), ('b', 2)])
>>> After:
>>> OrderedDict([('a', '1')])
```

As I said it is not exactly reproducible, at least I was not able to reproduce it in a simple case (so sorry twice). However, in my broader context (with large class and big method) I face this situation. For debugging purposes I also put two print statements (just like above - one before the return and another right after the call). So, all this seems to me like some side effect. And I'm not asking for a solution, but for some advice on how to do some extra debugging.

**screen 1**

[image]

**screen 2**

[image]

**screen 3**

[image]

So, as you can see from these screens, I first call `join_aliases_tables`, this method calls some static method `SQL_Utils.attrs_tables_set` (which does some modification of `attrs_tables` argument), after this modification I do my first print, then return and then the second print.

**EDIT**

However, if I do the sligthest change in the world - return my `attrs_tables` argument - then it starts working. So, if I do:

```
print("BEFORE:")
print(attrs_tables)                
return join_str, attrs_tables 

#and

join_str, attrs_tables = self.join_aliases_tables(table_name, attrs, attrs_as, \
                                            attrs_case, join, descs, \
                                            attrs_extra, attrs_tables, \
                                            alias_tables, table_alias, \
                                            tables, alias, where, \
                                            cache_case)                                                
print("AFTER: ")
print(attrs_tables)
```

then I see a nice picture in the console:
[image]

So, for some insane reason I have to return my mutable object to see all changes, if I do not return it, then I get a strange picture.

**Demonstration**

```
from collections import OrderedDict as dord

class FirstClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def changeIt(d):
        d['b'] = 'b'

class SecondClass(object):
     def __init__(self):
        pass
     def test(self, d):
        d = dord((k.upper(), v.upper()) for k, v in d.items())
        FirstClass.changeIt(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    d = dord({'a':'a'})
    t = SecondClass()
    t.test(d)
    print(d)
```

Comment: Just tried your code, it works as expected. We can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: Try breaking up this huge method into smaller methods. It will be easy for others to understand when they read your code and it is easier to debug smaller methods.

Comment: Well, the catch is, in my real case I also pass OrderedDict argument to the method and I also print this argument before return and after the call. And the contents of this argument is different.

Comment: FYI, your `BEFORE` is really printing the dict after it's modified so I don't know how you end up seeing what you see on the console.

Comment: @muratgu. I also do not know, but this is what I see. I will try to make a reproducible example, but it may contain a lot of code and it may take some time

Comment: Well, there is too much code (> 300 lines to reproduce all calls), but I will provide three screens to prove that I'm not joking.

Comment: The only thing I can think of without seeing your code is that your test function/method is not really changing the OrderedDict you've passed, but a copy of it. You should really try to generate a small test case capable of reproducing your issue.

Comment: But what can make it a copy from the original OrderedDict?

Comment: YAHOO!! I reproduced it. In a minite I will present the code.

Comment: Please, have a look at my example. Now it is completely reproducible.

Comment: You're creating a new dictionary with `d = dord((k.upper(), v.upper()) for k, v in d.items())`. That's the one that gets modified, not the one you originally passed.

Comment: @ Rawing. Why what is to the right is not assigned to the argument passed to the method? I see no logic behind it.

Comment: @Jacobian: You need to understand the difference between mutation and rebinding. Read [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your demonstration example

```
from collections import OrderedDict as dord

class FirstClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def changeIt(d):
        d['b'] = 'b'

class SecondClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def test(self, d):
        d = dord((k.upper(), v.upper()) for k, v in d.items())
        FirstClass.changeIt(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    d = dord({'a':'a'})
    t = SecondClass()
    t.test(d)
    print(d)
```

the `d` from main remain unchanged because you don't modify it at any time, when you call `t.test(d)` inside that function you create a new dict with `d = dord(...)`, remember that in python with `var = value` you create a new variable with that value even if that one have the same name of other variable somewhere else, and in that case you simple swap the reference to another object.

In the function `test` you pass a reference to the external `d` and keep it in a variable also called `d` then to this second `d` you assign a new reference to a new object losing the reference to the original one leaving unchanged in the process.

To fix this, as you want to change that external object you need to use the method that the object offer to this purpose, those that you access as `var.method`.

With the above example that can be

```
from collections import OrderedDict as dord

class FirstClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def changeIt(d):
        d['b'] = 'b'

class SecondClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def test(self, d):
        #save the temporary result
        temp = dord((k.upper(), v.upper()) for k, v in d.items())
        #empty the old one
        d.clear()
        #update with the new data
        d.update(temp)
        FirstClass.changeIt(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    d = dord({'a':'a'})
    t = SecondClass()
    t.test(d)
    print(d)
```

output

```
OrderedDict([('A', 'A'), ('b', 'b')])
```

But I don't recommend such practice, instead return the new object a assign it to the original variable.

Recommended lecture:

http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/

http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/